# Deciphering "Transport rejected package because it wasn't able to process it at the time" error in Android Auto Backup

Tags: java, android, encryption, backup

I've been attempting to follow along with the instructions on the [Android Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) documentation page. I keep hitting errors that prevent me from completing a backup of my app.

First, I added the following two lines to my AndroidManifest:

```
<application
  ...
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules"
  ...
</application>
```

I created a `my_backup_rules.xml` file in `android/app/src/main/res/xml` with the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="file" path="db.realm" />
</full-backup-content>
```

According to Android Studio, the `db.realm` file is rather large at 18MB, so this is the only file I'm planning to include in the backup to remain within the 25MB backup quota.

Following the [test documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup), I ran `adb shell bmgr list transports` and saw the following output:

```
* daemon started successfully
    com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport
    com.google.android.gms/.backup.migrate.service.D2dTransport
  * com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
```

However, when I run the next test `adb shell bmgr backupnow <PACKAGE>` I see the following error:

```
Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Transport rejected package because it wasn't able to process it at the time
Backup finished with result: Transport error
```

In `adb logcat`, I see the following:

```
08-12 12:19:28.007  2123  2123 V Bmgr    : Running backupnow for user:0
08-12 12:19:28.017   906  2524 D KeyValueBackupTask: Spinning thread key-value-backup-208
08-12 12:19:28.019   906  2147 D PFTBT   : backupmanager pftbt token=211e7180
08-12 12:19:28.023   906  2147 V KeyValueBackupTask: Beginning backup of 1 targets
08-12 12:19:28.059   906   906 I TransportClient: BackupTransportService#438: Notifying [KVBT.startTask()] transport = IBackupTransport
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  :      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:480)
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  :      at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy.name(IBackupTransport.java:869)
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  :      at com.android.server.backup.keyvalue.KeyValueBackupTask.startTask(KeyValueBackupTask.java:414)
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  :      at com.android.server.backup.keyvalue.KeyValueBackupTask.run(KeyValueBackupTask.java:344)
08-12 12:19:28.062   906  2147 W Binder  :      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
08-12 12:19:28.065   906  2147 D KeyValueBackupTask: Starting key-value backup of @pm@
08-12 12:19:28.095   906  2147 D KeyValueBackupTask: Invoking agent on @pm@
08-12 12:19:28.095   906  5761 D BackupTransportManager: Transport com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService updated its attributes
08-12 12:19:28.104   906  2147 V BackupAgentTimeout: getKvBackupAgentTimeoutMillis(): 30000
08-12 12:19:28.116   906  2147 I BackupRestoreController: Getting widget state for user: 0
08-12 12:19:28.157 29692 31059 I Backup  : [GmsBackupTransport] Performing encrypted kv backup: @pm@
08-12 12:19:28.252   906  2147 I RecoverableAppKeyStore: Get 0/10114/com.google.android.gms.backup/folsom/<TOKEN>
08-12 12:19:28.319   497   497 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
08-12 12:19:28.421   497   497 I chatty  : uid=9999(nobody) keymaster@3.0-s identical 2 lines
08-12 12:19:28.421   497   497 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
08-12 12:19:28.455 29692 29714 I gle.android.gm: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
08-12 12:19:28.482 29692 29714 I gle.android.gm: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 26.699ms
08-12 12:19:28.497 29692 29704 I gle.android.gm: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Background on ProfileSaver for 14.700ms
08-12 12:19:29.159 29692 31059 I Backup  : [GmsBackupTransport] Backup finished for @pm@
08-12 12:19:29.178   906  2147 I KeyValueBackupTask: K/V backup pass finished
08-12 12:19:29.179   906  2147 D KeyValueBackupTask: Starting full backups for: [<PACKAGE>]
08-12 12:19:29.184   906  2160 I PFTBT   : Initiating full-data transport backup of <PACKAGE> token: <TOKEN>
08-12 12:19:29.193 29692 31059 I Backup  : [GmsBackupTransport] Attempt to do full backup on <PACKAGE>
08-12 12:19:29.294 29692 31059 I Backup  : [FullBackupSession] Using encrypted processor for <PACKAGE>
08-12 12:19:29.335   906  2160 I RecoverableAppKeyStore: Get 0/10114/com.google.android.gms.backup/folsom/<TOKEN>
08-12 12:19:29.365   906  2160 I PFTBT   : Transport rejected backup of <PACKAGE>, skipping
08-12 12:19:29.365   906  2160 I PFTBT   : Unbinding agent in <PACKAGE>
08-12 12:19:29.366   906  2160 W ActivityManager: Unbinding backup agent with no active backup
08-12 12:19:29.366   906  2160 I PFTBT   : Full backup completed with status: 0
```

The `Transport rejected backup of <PACKAGE>, skipping` error message indicates that I'm over quota, according to the [Troubleshooting](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup#Troubleshooting) documentation. But my db.realm file is less than 25MB, and that's the only thing that I have set to back up in .xml, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Meanwhile, on my test device (a Pixel XL), I can go to Settings > System > Backup and confirm that "Back up to Google Drive" is switched on. Backups for other apps are working. I set a lock screen on my device, because that seemed to be one of the early issues I ran into that was preventing me from running a backup.

Any advice on how to get past this error?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It works fine in the emulator, but not on my phone. Did you end up finding the cause?

Comment: I didn't. It seems like there might need to be some processes that first run on the phone to make it work, because it worked for me after waiting ~24 hours.

Comment: The 24-hour wait didn't help me. The same error started showing on another device once I crossed the 25MB per app Google Drive limit.

Comment: Got the same problem, found a workaround in a forum - I've canceled the screen lock, and then it worked - https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-google-backup-waiting-to-backup.3895101/page-5 (see post #91).